# css list alignment for three items

Tags: html, css, list

i have some css to align two parts of a list item to the left and right side like so :-

```
 ul li div.left {
   float:left;
 }
 ul li {
   text-align:right;
 }

 <ul>
   <li><div class="left">On the left</div>On the right</li>
 </ul>
```

Is it possible to extend the above to add one more part that aligns to the bottom left below the left and right parts?

i have tried :-

```
<li><div class="left">On the left</div>On the right<p><div class="left">At the bottom<div></p></li>
```

but it doesnt render correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify your HTML structure like I've done below and then style accordingly to create the sort of a layout which you want.

Here's a working demo:

```css
ul {
  padding: 0px;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li.left {
  float: left;
}
ul li.right {
  float: right;
}
ul li.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.block {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div class="block">
    <li class="left">On the left</li>
    <li class="right">On the right</li>
  </div>
  <li class="center">centered underneath</li>
</ul>
```